# how to specify thumbprint when creating cluster?

Tags: powershell, ssl, https, azure-service-fabric, tls1.2

I can create a secure cluster by running the command

```
.\DevClusterSetup.ps1 -AsSecureCluster -CreateOneNodeCluster -Auto
```

[image]

**Instead of allowing SF to create its own certificate, how can I specify a certificate for it to use?**

Please note that this is not an azure deployment. This is on-premises.

Comment: Have a look at [THIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-security-update-certs-azure)

Comment: that won't work on premises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> .\CreateServiceFabricCluster.ps1 -ClusterConfigFilePath
>   .\ClusterConfig.X509.MultiMachine.json

More info here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-windows-cluster-x509-security